# Execute a statement without specifying a table

Tags: mysql, oracle

`select 2 + 2` is a valid mysql statement, but in oracle I have to provide a table name `select 2 + 2 from foo` (or `dual` table). Is there any way to not set the `from` statement? I wonder why it is not optional in Oracle. Providing a fake table sounds dummy when it could be optional as other RDBMs.

Comment: I don't think so, but if you are not comfortable in giving the name of table created by you you can mention dual, ie select 2+2 from dual;

Comment: selecting from dual is also an option in mysql

Answer (score 3):

You have to select from *something*; in Oracle, it is the `DUAL` table:

```
SQL> select 3 + 6 from dual;

       3+6
----------
         9
```

It is a `SYS` owned table and contains a single row:

```
SQL> select * From dual;

DUMMY
--------------------
X
```

Therefore, it is useful for such things (where you need to fetch a single line).

The way you put it (`select ... from foo`) is kind of OK, if foo also contains one row. But, what if it doesn't? Have a look: there are 4 departments in the `dept` table:

```
SQL> select 3 + 6 from dept;

       3+6
----------
         9
         9
         9
         9
```

So - use `DUAL` :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [PL/SQL Subprograms](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#CHDDCFHD) in Oracle you can execute 2 + 2, for example

```
DECLARE
    v_sum number;
BEGIN
    v_sum:= 2 + 2;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to SQL in general, but from SQL* Plus or in other ides running as script(F5), you can do arithmetic without specifying a table

```
VARIABLE b NUMBER
EXEC :b := 2+2;
PRINT b;


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

         B
----------
         4
```

Answer (score 0):

use dual because it  is a single row single column table with a datatype of VARCHAR2(1) in it.ALways use dual when you want to fetch single output.it has a dummy value of X.
AS wiki says :- The idea was that you could do a JOIN to the DUAL table and create two rows in the result for every one row in your table. Then, by using GROUP BY, the resulting join could be summarized to show the amount of storage for the DATA extent and for the INDEX extent(s). The name, DUAL, seemed apt for the process of creating a pair of rows from just one.[1]

The original DUAL table had two rows in it (hence its name), but subsequently it only had one row.